# Laravel Homestead Installation: bash init.sh not working

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel, homestead

I'm trying to install Laravel Homestead in order to be able to test my Laravel projects locally.

I'm following this tutorial: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

In the "Installing Homestead" part I followed the second step "Manually Via Git (No Local PHP)",I don't have any PHP installed locally and can't use Composer. (Wasn't PHP supposed to be installed as part of Homestead?)

I got to this part:

> Once you have installed the Homestead CLI tool, run the bash init.sh command to create the Homestead.yaml configuration file:
>
> bash init.sh

In command prompt I tried to enter the following command:

```
bash init.sh
```

I got the following error:

```
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Then I tried to enter the same command in Git Bash, and I got the following error:

> bash: init.sh: No such file or directory

When I tried to enter in Git Bash simply

`init.sh`

I got the following error:

`sh.exe": init.sh: command not found`

Comment: try to run this command from command line: 

mkdir -p ~/.homestead
cp src/stubs/Homestead.yaml ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
cp src/stubs/after.sh ~/.homestead/after.sh
cp src/stubs/aliases ~/.homestead/aliases

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/.homestead` results in `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: If you are using Windows, try to specify full path C:\Users\UserName\.homestead

Comment: First command worked. Second command: `cp src/stubs/Homestead.yaml D:/Homestead/Homestead.yaml` results in `'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Copy its a windows cp command. Or better copy this files manualy. :)

Comment: I copied all 3 files from src/stubs to that new directory. What did it accomplish?

Comment: Configure Your Shared Folders\Nginx sites etc... and vagrant up

Comment: I simply executed init.sh in my Homestead folder, is that fine? Said "Homestead Initialized!". Should I modify the Homestead.yaml I have there? If not then why not? Why going through copying only some files from there to a new folder?

Comment: `chmod +x init.sh` and `./init.sh`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you ShellFish

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this problem well. You need to hop into your terminal (I am on Mac.)

- Type into your console: `cd ~/Homestead`
- and to make sure you are in your newly generated Homestead folder (you can always click `Finder > your home directory > Homestead` to confirm it's where it should be),
- then while in terminal simply type `ls` -- if it lists all of the files like `Vagrantfile`, `composer.lock` and bash `init.sh`, you should be in.

Once you know you are in the correct Homestead folder, it is **now at that point** in which you run `bash init.sh`

After doing this it now says `Homestead initialized!`

Answer (score 8):

**.sh** is a *unix/linux script executable*, that isn't recognized on **Windows**.  There's a *init.bat* included in the package, but it isn't referenced in the tutorial.

Just run *init.bat* from the command line.  It will copy the files to:

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.homestead
```

Answer (score 0):

You need install Git Bash, and then run commands into Git Bash.

Comment: Like I wrote, I did try Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try `init.bat` that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If the init.bat refused to work

Go to the Homestead folder.
C:/Users/Computer Name/Homestead

You will see init.bat: double click to run it.

Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer you may be looking for. I was having the same problems with this. Just make sure at the end of bash init.sh you put a ;

So in the git bash cmd you will have this line

$ bash init.sh;

Answer (score -2):

Just do it using sudo.

```
$sudo bash init.sh
```